# Ajax Response JSON data to select box in html

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, multidimensional-array

below is my ajax call and i am getting r JSON data

```
$.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getrecieverlist.php",
            data: { strSenderID: sendmeid },
            success: function (r) { 
            }
       });
```

I am getting r response as JSON data below

```
{
 "receiverDetails": [
{
  "receiver_id": "55555",
  "name": "Nitin",
  "mobile": "7777777777",
  "ifsc_code": "IFSC54545",
  "acc_no": "16-01-2017"
},
{
  "receiver_id": "66666",
  "name": "Vikram",
  "mobile": "9191919191",
  "ifsc_code": "IFSC54545",
  "acc_no": "13-01-2017"
}
],
 "success": 1
 }
```

and my select box html code is below

```
<select id="recieverlist" name="select" class="main-form">
      <option value="">None Selected</option>
    </select>
```

what i want is to populate select box options with text as name from the JSON data and value of the options to be receiverid, i tried many things but did not worked out for me need the proper guide how to do it?

Comment: That's a simple loop to generate a DOM string/`<option>` with the value of a property, which is than appended to the DOM. _"i tried many things"_ - Than show us your attempts and we can try to fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on following.

```
success : function (r) {
    var data = r.receiverDetails;
    var options = '';

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { // Loop through the data & construct the options
        options += '<option value="'+data[i].receiver_id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
    }

    // Append to the html
    $('#recieverlist').append(options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also $.each function.

```
                $.each(data.receiverDetails, function(index, value)
                    $("#recieverlist").append('<option value="'+value.receiver_id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                  });
```

Comment: You can even do:
`$('<option></option>').text(value.name).val(value.receiver_id);`